# Ajax canvas chart doesn't display changest?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, canvas

Hi guys i have a problem on how should i properly display this chart dynamic.

this code is when i selecting category and date , the chart will change according to value of each select then
[image]
**Dropdown Category and Date Filter:**

```
<form class="form-inline" method='get'>
  <div class="form-group">

        <select name="category" id="category" onchange="showCategory(this.value)">
        <option value="ACCOUNT REGISTER" >ACCOUNT REGISTER</option>
        <option value="ACCOUNT UNREGISTER" >ACCOUNT UNREGISTER</option>
        <option value="CATEGORY 1">CATEGORY 1</option>
        <option value="CATEGORY 2">CATEGORY 2</option>
        <option value="CATEGORY 3">CATEGORY 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="monthx" type="month" name="monthx" onchange="filter_datex(this.value)">
    </div>

  <select class="form-control input-sm" id="chartType" name="Chart Type">
    <option value="line">Line</option>
    <option value="column">Column</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    <option value="pie">Pie</option>
    <option value="doughnut">Doughnut</option>
  </select>  
    <div class="form-group">
        <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" onclick="printDoc()"  target="_blank" >PRINT</a>
    </div>

</form>
```

rendered chart will go to this code here !

**CHART:**

```
  <div  id="printDiv" >
    <div id="displayChart">
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {

    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
      animationEnabled: true,
      title: {
        text: "First Default Chart Before Onchange"
      },
      data: [{
        type: "pie",
        startAngle: 240,
        yValueFormatString: "##0.00'%'",
        indexLabel: "{label} {y}",
        dataPoints: [
          {y: 79.45, label: "Student"},
          {y: 7.31, label: "Admin"},
          {y: 7.06, label: "Teacher"}
        ]
      }]
    });
    chart.render();
    var chartType = document.getElementById('chartType');
    chartType.addEventListener( "change",  function(){
      chart.options.data[0].type = chartType.options[chartType.selectedIndex].value;
      chart.render();
    });

    }
    </script>

  </div>
</div>
```

i use the previous answer code of @Krishnadas PC then this is now my JavaScript and right now the title is changing

**JSCRIPT:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getDate(){
    var monthx =document.getElementById('monthx').value;

  }
  function getCategory(){
    var category =document.getElementById('category').value;

  }
  function printDoc(){
    var getCategory = getCategory();
    var getDate = getDate();
    window.location='assets/lib/FPDF/print?category='+getCategory+'&date='+getDate;

  }
  $('#monthx').hide();
  function showCategory(str) {
  var xhttp; 
  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("displayChart").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  if (str == "ACCOUNT REGISTER" || str == "ACCOUNT UNREGISTER" || str == "default") {
    $('#monthx').hide();
  }
  else{
    $('#monthx').show();
  }
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {


                    var json_datax = this.responseText;
                    var monthx =document.getElementById('monthx').value;
                    var category =document.getElementById('category').value;

                    console.log(this.responseText)
                    var chart=new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                        animationEnabled: true, title: {
                            text: ''+category+" "+monthx+''
                        }
                        , data: [ {
                            type: "pie", startAngle: 240, yValueFormatString: "##0.00'%'", indexLabel: "{label} {y}", dataPoints: 
                            [ {
                                y: 79.45, label: 3123
                            }
                            , {
                                y: 7.31, label: "x"
                            }
                            , {
                                y: 7.06, label: "Baidu"
                            }
                            , {
                                y: 4.91, label: "Yahoo"
                            }
                            , {
                                y: 11.26, label: "Others"
                            }
                            ]
                        }
                        ]
                    }
                    );
                    chart.render();
                    var chartType=document.getElementById('chartType');

                    chartType.addEventListener( "change", function() {
                        chart.options.data[0].type=chartType.options[chartType.selectedIndex].value;
                        chart.render();
                    }
                    );
                }
            };
  xhttp.open("GET", "chart_ajax.php?category="+str+"&date="+monthx, true);
  xhttp.send();
}

  function filter_datex(str) {
  var xhttp; 
  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("displayChart").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    var json_datax = this.responseText;
                    var monthx =document.getElementById('monthx').value;
                    var category =document.getElementById('category').value;
                    console.log(this.responseText)
                    var chart=new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                        animationEnabled: true, title: {
                            text: ''+category+" "+monthx+''
                        }
                        , data: [ {
                            type: "pie", startAngle: 240, yValueFormatString: "##0.00'%'", indexLabel: "{label} {y}", dataPoints: 
                            [ {
                                y: 79.45, label: 3123
                            }
                            , {
                                y: 7.31, label: "x"
                            }
                            , {
                                y: 7.06, label: "Baidu"
                            }
                            , {
                                y: 4.91, label: "Yahoo"
                            }
                            , {
                                y: 11.26, label: "Others"
                            }
                            ]
                        }
                        ]
                    }
                    );
                    chart.render();
                    var chartType=document.getElementById('chartType');

                    chartType.addEventListener( "change", function() {
                        chart.options.data[0].type=chartType.options[chartType.selectedIndex].value;
                        chart.render();
                    }
                    );
                }
            };
  xhttp.open("GET", "chart_ajax.php?category="+monthx+"&date="+str, true);
  xhttp.send();
  }

</script>
```

then in my ajax page, the category and date values will be on POST on the page then `GET[]` the variable using get method and perform query base on get value, the result of query will be fetch as json or echo as a whole json code,

**CHART_AJAX.php**

```
include('db.php');
$category = $_GET['category'];
//$category_ID =  $_GET['category_ID'];
$date = $_GET['date'];
$sql = "MY QUERY $date and $category";
$result = $con->query();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

$data  = json_encode($row['json']);

print_r ($data);
//result or print_r ($data)
//[ {
//    y: 79.45, label: 3123
//}
//, {
//    y: 7.31, label: "x"
//}
//, {
//    y: 7.06, label: "Baidu"
//}
//, {
//    y: 4.91, label: "Yahoo"
//}
//, {
//    y: 11.26, label: "Others"
//}
//]
```

what i want is the result of print_r from chart_ajax.php must be pass on js var instead of 
var json_data = //pass the ajax_chart.php result then

```
data: [ {
    type: "pie", startAngle: 240, yValueFormatString: "##0.00'%'", indexLabel: "{label} {y}", dataPoints: 
    //this var json_data will be go here or else 
    //the result of ajax_chart.php must be go here !!! directly? 
}
]
```

then i want in print button is , when i click that it must go to new tab like `target="_BLANK"` not SELF windows location ?

```
    function getDate(){
        var monthx =document.getElementById('monthx').value;

      }

  function getCategory(){
    var category =document.getElementById('category').value;

  }
  function printDoc(){
    var getCategory = getCategory();
    var getDate = getDate();
    window.location='assets/lib/FPDF/print?category='+getCategory+'&date='+getDate;

  }
```

Comment: Is the change listener correctly working? Normally in js libraries you need to renitialize them once a change is made from the server side. The onload functions will not run after the ajax response. You may need to renitialize the chart with new data after the ajax response then it may work. Couldn't check the codes since from a mobile device.

Comment: @krishnadas i don't get how to fix this is :( . but the other variable still changing when on-change occur. hmm .. but the chart doesn't render changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you are trying to achieve by using the ajax. There is only one title that is taken from **$_GET**. You can return only that  from the ajax file. The remaining code can be inside ajax response section. The changes will work then. I have tested it here.

In **chart_ajax.php**

```
   <?php echo $title=$_GET['q'];
```

In a real application you can fetch the values for the graph from a database or some other third party apis and return only the data as json. No need to render html and loop those data and build the updated graph at the client(browser) side.

In your main file update the ajax response section like this.

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("displayChart").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    console.log(this.responseText)
                    var chart=new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                        animationEnabled: true, title: {
                            text: '"'+this.responseText+'"'
                        }
                        , data: [ {
                            type: "pie", startAngle: 240, yValueFormatString: "##0.00'%'", indexLabel: "{label} {y}", dataPoints: [ {
                                y: 79.45, label: 3123
                            }
                            , {
                                y: 7.31, label: "Bing"
                            }
                            , {
                                y: 7.06, label: "Baidu"
                            }
                            , {
                                y: 4.91, label: "Yahoo"
                            }
                            , {
                                y: 11.26, label: "Others"
                            }
                            ]
                        }
                        ]
                    }
                    );
                    chart.render();
                    var chartType=document.getElementById('chartType');
                    chartType.addEventListener( "change", function() {
                        chart.options.data[0].type=chartType.options[chartType.selectedIndex].value;
                        chart.render();
                    }
                    );
                }
            };
```

These changes will update the graph but this won't make a real application.

Comment: Yow I Use This Code and Its Work And Also I Update My Post, I Want To Achieve Is Creating A Dynamic Chart And 2 Drop-down Will Be Responsible for  Category and Date And Send Their Value to Ajax_file, then the result of ajax_file will be throw json_data like  `{
                                y: 7.06, label: "Baidu"
                            }
                            , {
                                y: 4.91, label: "Yahoo"
                            }` to dynamicaly change the chart value

Comment: You have all the required data in the ajax response. Build the chart object from that this.responseText. I recommend you to learn the basics first before actually trying.

Comment: so the whole result of ajax_file will be go to `this.responseText` then i tried to store this to 1 variable then put the variable in center of data: [ ] in the chart , then its still not working

Comment: It will work only if you build the object in the required format as mentioned in the sample code. Am currently from a mobile device and couldn't do coding. Are you getting the correct ajax response? If that is correct you can easily build that object. First try to learn how can we create the objects.  http://javascript.info is a good source.

Comment: ah ok, right now i don't have stable internet, i know how to understand object, maybe i just use the wrong way of method, hmm ,